# How to - Custom 404 Not Found php

Tags: php, errordocument

I was looking for this over google and found just one thing repeated on every single website.

Edit your .htaccess and add this line:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /yourpage.php
```

So for example my page is error.php so it is obvious that it should be:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
```

However even if I type full domain name it doesnt works. It gives me Internal Server Error only and I have no ideas how to make it.

Any tips? Thanks.

EDIT No.1:
I am not quite sure where do I check for these "Apache" logs.

Btw here is full ISE Message:

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, *webmaster@mydomainname.com* and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Also I have tried making error.html and doesnt works. And also I Do not use any other rewrites in htaccess.

Comment: What is the error message in your log? If you're receiving a **500 internal server error** it will be stored in either your php or apache error log (if you're using apache, of course).

Comment: Try it first with a html file. If your error.php contains errors itself....... (Been there, done that) ;-)

Comment: Also interested in your log? If you have other rewrite conditions, keep them in mind when you add an errordocumente. For example, I remove the extension (.php) on my site, so my ErrorDocument is just "404 /404"

Answer (score 0):

Then your webserver does not support this option...
Look into your http.conf and search for

```
AllowOverride <value>
```

If it is not equal FileInfo or all configuring error documents is not allowed.
Change it to All to make it work (and restart Apache afterwards)
If you do not have access to the http.conf, ask your Provider to allow custom error documents.